# Tinymce doesnt appear

Tags: php, javascript, html, dreamweaver

I downloaded and put the directory of tinymce into my site folder..

I used the following javascript scripts in the head of my html page..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "simple",
        mode : "textareas",
        convert_urls : false
    });
</script>
```

My body contains this:

```
<textarea name="textareas" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I read that the javascript should replace the textarea for the tinymce html editor. But it doesnt do it..

ps. I get no errors while running the script.

Here is the full page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>צור כתבה</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
       mode : "textareas",
       theme : "simple",
       editor_selector :"mceEditor"
    });

</script> 
</head>

<body>


<div align="center" id="htmlEditor">
  <textarea name="textareas" cols="40" rows="20" class="mceEditor"></textarea>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

shouldnt the textarea be converted to a tinymce?!?!?

Comment: Please see: [I have a question, what information should I provide so that somebody can help me with an answer?](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#I_have_a_question.2C_what_information_should_I_provide_so_that_somebody_can_help_me_with_an_answer.3F)

Comment: It is such a simple code..why to close?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not end your script tag with `/>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>`

instead of

`<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>`

Comment: @Dmitry It's important, that. Anyway, did you check the path to tiny_mce.js is right?

Comment: sorry! problem seems to be `editor_selector :"mceEditor"` see: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_selector

Comment: what was the problem..?!?? I didnt add a class :(..I updated, It still ownt work

Comment: hmmm..sorry, It actually started to work... I need to udapt it.. But thanks